# Stack Exchange site for other sports

Tags: discussion, area-51

We have Stack Exchange sites for chess and board and card games but not for other sports like tennis and cricket. Why is that?

Comment: Because no-one thought of trying to create such a site or managed to build enough of a community for one (yet)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is a site for sports: http://sports.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

Such sites are proposed from time to time on Area51.  Ones for Cricket and Football were recently closed from lack of support.

Propose one.

Comment: Oh.. I was not aware of Area51.. Thanks..